# Как в Spring фильтровать переменные формы?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Есть проект на **Spring Boot**
Как мне входящие данные из формы фильтровать?
Допустим в объекте `TestDTO` есть поле `phone`, до валидации я хочу удалить все не числовые символы и далее валидация, как мне этого достичь?

Есть DTO объект.

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestDTO {

    @Email
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a email")
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Size(min = 10)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a phone")
    @NotNull
    private String phone;
}
```

Есть конструктор с методом.

```java
@Log4j2
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/admin/system")
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/contact")
    public ModelAndView contactSave(
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            @Valid TestDTO testDTO,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            ModelAndView model) {

        log.info(testDTO);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Form has error");
        }


        log.error("Form success");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение следующие (если есть более лучшее, пожалуйста добавьте в ответ)
Создаем класс, расширяющий `PropertyEditorSupport`, далее регистрируем его в контроллоре в `WebDataBinder`. Наглядно в листинге.

**PhoneEditor.class** - удаление всех не числовых символов

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

@Component
public class PhoneEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (null != text) {
            // Удаляем все не числовые символы
            this.setValue(text.replaceAll("[\\D]+", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

**TrimEditor.class** - для удаление всех пробелов

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

@Component
public class TrimEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (null != text) {
            // Удаляем все пробелы
            this.setValue(text.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

**TestController.class**

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import uz.gigalab.ecommerce.editor.PhoneEditor;
import uz.gigalab.ecommerce.editor.TrimEditor;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Log4j2
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    @InitBinder("contact")
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "phone", new PhoneEditor());
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new TrimEditor());
    }

    @PostMapping("/contact")
    public ModelAndView contactSave(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("contact") TestDTO testDTO,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            ModelAndView model) {

        log.info(testDTO);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Form has error");
            return model;
        }

        log.error("Form success");
        return model;
    }
}
```